# EnableViewState property in textbox

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody tell me please that how can we use the enableviewstate property of textbox in asp.net.
By making it false or true how can we feel a difference in result.

Comment: I suggest you read through http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx - there are a lot of nuances to using viewstate and this is a great article

Comment: that is self explanatory,isn't it?

Comment: we feel a difference between it is 'cheating' HTTP. MVC FTW. (ok i realise that isnt helpful but i couldnt help myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET has EnableViewState set to true, this is why when you do a Postback, the values are retained in the TextBoxes.

If you set it to false, and do a Postback, **ka-boom**! The value is no longer there :)

Comment: My textbox value is still there :( even when I set both page and control `enableviewstate="false"`

Comment: I am just trying the same, but even if i make the EnableViewState="false", the value of the textbox is retaining even we do a postback.. Plz explain the reason.

Comment: @Amit, see my answer below for this behavior (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724137/enableviewstate-property-in-textbox/3724274#3724274)

Answer (score 7):

It depends upon what properties we are talking about. For example, many properties such as Visible, Enabled, Appearance related properties such as CssClass, BackColor etc are backed by view-state and will not be retained over post-back if you disable the view-state.

**Text property** (value within text-box) is a different case - this property will be backed by both post data and view-state. So even if view-state is disabled, you will see the value being retained because its get read via POST data (Request.Form collection). But you will notice the difference if you mark the text box read-only or marked its visibility false. In both these cases, the text value will be retrieved from view-state and disabling it will result in loss of value over a post-back.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `EnableViewState = true` than value will be saved between post backs. When you set this property to false each new responce `TextBox` will have value provided by your code or will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you set enableviewstate = true, then after the postback values will be retained in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

This property is used to decide whether to keep the value after the postback or not. If it's sets to false the value will not maintain possession with every postback. Whatever is entered by user will be gone. And in case of textbox you don't have to change this property in most cases or I can say all cases.