# How to use EnableViewState with TextBox (by setting "false", it doesn't work)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just started learning ASP.NET, did some practice with TextBox and Button - getting sum of two numbers.

I want the TextBoxes Not to retain their values after clicking the button, by setting the EnableViewState = "false". This doesn't work and by searching posts, I got some explanations on this issue...The problem is, with all the explanations, I can't manage to find a solution.

There are some possible ways I found by searching, to make the TextBox not retain its value:

1. setting the TextBox to "": TextBox1.Text ="" 
   source: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2004/03/15/2273.aspx
   didn't work for me..
2. "...mark the text box read-only or marked its visibility false..."
   source: [EnableViewState property in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724137/enableviewstate-property-in-textbox/3724274#3724274)
   didn't work too...

My code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstNumber" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSecondNumber" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSum" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"onclick="btnAdd_Click1" />
```

code-behind page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtFirstNumber.Text);
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtSecondNumber.Text);
    int c = a + b;

    txtSum.Text = c.ToString();
}
```

Comment: textbox's don't use viewstate. Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064621/i-have-one-issue-for-viewstate/16064714

Comment: @user814064 Thanks. I read that post before. If txtbox doesn't use viewstate, how do I make it not retain the value after clicking the button...

Comment: @user814064 - TextBox does use viewstate. Read your link. It says viewstate is not the only way textbox retains it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear out a text box, set its `Text` property to `null` or `""`:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtFirstNumber.Text);
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtSecondNumber.Text);
    int c = a + b;

    txtSum.Text = c.ToString();
    txtFirstNumber.Text = "";
    txtSecondNumber.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael! This worked...Now every time when the btn is clicked, those two txtboxes are cleared out. 
It was definitely my fault saying that by setting the .Text to "" didn't work, since I put them in the Page_Load method.

Comment: additional question: by setting the text to "" or null, is it the same fundamental/mechanism as not retaining the value with EnableViewState = false? or just a way of working around the problem? Are there any other ways of doing this if the EnableViewState doesn't apply in such case

Comment: @defaultuser- viewstate is not the only way that textbox retains its value. And the solution shows proper way of clearing textboxes. It is not a workaround. So you should stick to it.

Comment: @defaultuser: If you want to clear the text boxes when the user clicks Add, then this is the best and most straightforward way to do that. A TextBox control does *not* use view state to retain its value across postbacks (if it's visible, enabled, and not read-only), so naturally setting EnableViewState to false won't prevent it from retaining its value.