# not need to use Viewstate to retain state in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I saw some code using Viewstate to retain state between user requests, below is the code to use a button to increment the number in a textbox input:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int ClicksCount = 1;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "0";
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ViewState["Clicks"] != null)
        {
            ClicksCount = (int)ViewState["Clicks"] + 1;
        }
        TextBox1.Text = ClicksCount.ToString(); ;
        ViewState["Clicks"] = ClicksCount;
    }
}
```

But I don't need to use Viewstate to achieve the same goal, and it is much more simple, here is my code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "0";
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            i++;
            TextBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

so what's wrong with my code

Comment: Whats your issue? @slowjams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code: the contents of the ASP.NET controls (as is the *TextBox1* in your example) are already integrated in the *ViewState* automatically, and hence there is no need to manually enter them. You would use directly the ViewState to store anything that is not part of your design components (for instance an int variable that you want to increase each time).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have set EnableViewState="False" for the textBox, why it is still retaining value?

Comment: @slowjams: the Text field of the textbox is retained by the posted values, as is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724137/enableviewstate-property-in-textbox/3724274#3724274

Comment: sorry, I still don't get it why it only works when text box is set to read-only?

Comment: When the textbox is not read only the value entered by the user is part of the posted values, and hence is kept. If it is read only the value is not stored in the posted values, and hence it is lost in a post back.