# UserControll form control(Textbox, DropDownList) data loss on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

Here is UserControl

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="NewPickageHeadTXT" runat="server" MaxLength="150" ClientIDMode="Static" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>    
    <asp:LinkButton ID="np_next" runat="server" Text="გაგრძელება" OnClick="np_next_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="newpickage btn blue"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>



protected void np_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int ClientID;
     if (int.TryParse(Session["ClientID"].ToString(), out ClientID) && FormIsValid())
     {
         string NewPickageHead = NewPickageHeadTXT.Text;
     }
}
bool FormIsValid()
{
    bool IsValid = true;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewPickageHeadTXT.Text))
    {
         IsValid = false;
    }
    return IsValid;
}
```

NewPickageHeadTXT.Text is Empty on LinkButton's Postback

And btw there is no data update (like this => NewPickageHeadTXT.Text = "some text") in any of page life circle events.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

This post [EnableViewState property in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724137/enableviewstate-property-in-textbox) probably help you.

Alternatively, you can use Ajax partial postback.
Since you are using web form, I would recommend to use AjaxcontrolToolkit. 
Put your link button in update Panel.
Example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlPostbackArea" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
     Your Linkbutton
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope it will solve your problem.